# Appending a point at infinity to $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: notation, terminology

Is there any standard notation for the set $\{\infty\}\cup \mathbb{F}_q$?
Thanks, and feel free to move if there is a better forum for this question.

Comment: $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb F_q)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual notation for projective space works fine over finite fields. You can consider the set of lines in $\mathbb{F}_q\times\mathbb{F}_q$, or equivalently, the set of ordered pairs $[x:y]$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{F}_q$ not both zero, modulo the relation $[x:y]\sim [\lambda x:\lambda y]$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}_q^\times$. Then $\mathbb{F}_q=\{[x:1]\}: x\in \mathbb{F}_q\}$ and $\infty=[1:0]$. The whole construction is referred to as the projective line over $\mathbb{F}_q$, or $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it was not what I was hoping for. Of course I am working with projective space over a field - I would not have had this question otherwise. I was hoping there was a compact notation, like $\hat{\mathbb{F}_q}$, $\bar{\mathbb{F}_q}$, or $\mathbb{F}_q^{\infty}$. This is by analogy with the Reimann sphere, for instance.

Comment: Then the best notation is probably, as Georges posted, $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_q)$. It's more standard than the options you suggested, and still reasonably concise.